# How to merge multiple file descriptors into the one?

Tags: c++, c, file, parent-child

In my C++ application I use some call to 3rd party lib for creating a new child process. I'm passing 2 `FILE**` variables to it and they being filled by pointers of `stdout` and `stderr` handlers of the child process. But in fact I don't need to read from them separately in separate threads, I just need to merge them into the one and read from there. How can I do that (both linux and Windows)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `dup2` ([manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

dup2(fileno(stdout), fileno(stderr));
```

Answer (score 0):

A file descriptor is linked by the system to a physic file. Merging two files descriptor into one would lead to get only one file.

If you always have those two file descriptors together, you can simply create a struct that would handle the two files descriptor in only one variable pointer.

Comment: Of course I can, but the thing I want is to have them merged. It will make my life easier giving ability to read those files from single thread. Such thing should be done in shell, say when we write `command 2>&1`, and then getting both logs merged in stdout. So I want to know how that 2>&1 implemented there.